# Storing coordinates in Matlab and calculating Euclidean distance

Tags: matlab

I want to store a randomly generated set of co-ordinates in Matlab using a 2D array which should look like this

array =     X    Y

```
   t1  x1    y1
   t2  x2    y2
   t3  x3    y3
       ...   ...
   tn  xn    yn
```

where t<sub>i</sub> is the i-th point in a 2D plane and has co-ordinates (x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>)

After creating this array, I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between t<sub>i</sub> and t<sub>j</sub> for all 1≤i,j≤n. How can this be achieved in Matlab?

Comment: try using `pdist2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N = 10; % # of points
X = rand(N, 1); % random coordinates
Y = rand(N, 1);
[X1, X2] = meshgrid(X);
[Y1, Y2] = meshgrid(Y);
d = sqrt((X1-X2).^2 + (Y1-Y2).^2); % pairwise distance in NxN, diag 0
```

The upper or lower triangle should contain the distance from

```
pdist([X Y]) % vector, not a matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bsxfun` to replicate operations over arrays.

```
N = 10;
p = rand(N,2); % coordinates
d = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,p(:,1),p(:,1)').^2+bsxfun(@minus,p(:,2),p(:,2)').^2);
```

The first `bsxfun` replicates the X coords in `p(:,1)` and `p(:,1)'` into NxN matrices by expanding the singleton dimension and the result is the subtraction of these matrices. Similarly, the second `bsxfun`. The rest is just array operations to square, sum and square root.

If you happen to have the statistics toolbox you can use `pdist`, but this gives a row vector corresponding to the lower triangle of `d`.